# trying to post an array in a db without success

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a form which allows me to create  a new user:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; 
require_once '../../db_con.php'; 

try{
    $results = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM cat_list");

}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$category = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

    <form action="actions/add_emp.php" method="post">

      <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" required="required"  /><br/>
      <input type="text" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password"/></label><br/>

      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="id"/>

        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Firstname"/><br />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="email" required="required" placeholder="Lastname"/><br/>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="city" required="required" placeholder="Email Address"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="extension" id="extension" required="required" placeholder="Extension Number"/><br/>
        <select name="title">
            <option  selected disabled>Please Select a Job Title...</option>

            <option disabled></option>
            <option disabled>Helpesk:</option>
            <option value="Technical Support Advisor">Technical Support Advisor</option>
            <option value="Deputy Team Leade">Deputy Team Leader</option>
            <option value="Team Leader">Team Leader</option>
            <option value="Incident Resolution Advisor">Incident Resolution Advisor</option>

            <option disabled></option>
            <option disabled>Call Centre:</option>
            <option value="Technical Support Advisor">Technical Support Advisor</option>
            <option value="">Deputy Team Leader</option>
            <option value="">Team Leader</option>

            <option disabled></option>
        </select>


<div id="checkboxlist" >
    <?php
        foreach($category as $cat){ 
    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $cat["cat_id"]; ?>" name="cat_no[]" id="box1"> <?php echo $cat["cat_title"]; ?></a><br>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div> 

        <input type="submit" value="Add User" name="submit"/><br />
    </form>
```

My action script looks like this:

```
<?
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
/*******************************************************************
**  ACTION SCRIPT TO POST A NEW CATEGORY INTO THE DOC_LIST TABLE  **
*******************************************************************/


    if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    include_once'../../config.php';

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dashboardr",$username,$password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

    if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
        $password=$_POST['pass'];
        $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user_login` WHERE `username`=?");
        $sql->execute(array($_POST['user']));

    if($sql->fetchColumn()!=0){

    die("User Exists");


    }else{
        function rand_string($length) {
        $str="";
        $chars = "subinsblogabcdefghijklmanopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $size = strlen($chars);
        for($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++) {
        $str .= $chars[rand(0,$size-1)];
    }

    return $str; 
    }
        $p_salt = rand_string(20); 
        $site_salt="subinsblogsalt"; 
        $salted_hash = hash('sha256', $password.$site_salt.$p_salt);

        $sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_login` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `psalt`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `extension`) 
                VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $sql->execute(
        array($_POST['user'], $salted_hash, $p_salt, $_POST["firstname"], $_POST["lastname"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["extension"]));


    }



$userId = $dbh->lastInsertId();

/***********************************************************************
**  INSERTS THE ARRAY DEPENDING ON WHICH WAS CHECKED WITHIN THE FORM  **
***********************************************************************/


$sql = "INSERT INTO `user_cat_link_table`(`UserID`, `Cat_ID`) VALUES";
$values = "";
$params = [];

foreach($_POST["cat_no"] as $cat)

var_dump($_POST);


{

    $values.= "(?, ?), ";
    $params[] = $cat; // correct here
    $params[] = $userId;
}

    $values = substr($values, 0, -2);
    $sql.= $values;
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);       

    if ($dbh->query($sql)) {

    }else{}

    $dbh = null;
    }

    {
    header ('Location: ../list_emp.php?success=1');
    }

    }

}
```

Now when I do a `var_dump($_POST);` it gives me back the results I am expecting but just not posting into the join table:

```
array(9) { ["user"]=> string(19) "2342rrwersfsdfdffdf" ["pass"]=> string(3) "424" ["action"]=> string(2) "id" ["firstname"]=> string(5) "23423" ["lastname"]=> string(5) "23424" ["email"]=> string(26) "daniel.barrett@ricoh.co.uk" ["extension"]=> string(6) "312321" ["cat_no"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "61" } ["submit"]=> string(8) "Add User" }
```

I am taking the ID of the user that is about to be created by using `$userId = $dbh->lastInsertId();` and then linking that to the category ID that was selcted and post it into the koin table where it takes the users ID and the category ID selected.

Comment: first of all put `return $str; ` inside your function not outside. you will never get any value through this function if return is written outside.

Comment: foreach() will also not work. use foreach(){//write statements here} otherwise only single line will be executed i.e. : var_dump($_POST);

Comment: I'm not sure your foreach loop syntax is correct, I would echo the `input` inside the foreach loop brackets, done all with PHP and no divide it up, though, it might be alright as well the way you did it.

Comment: var_dump is showing that there is one category posted from webpage whose id is 61.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Would you be able to show me an example of what you mena, sorry I am a little confused?

Comment: @JitendraKhatri that is correct because I only selected 1 category form the options.

Comment: @odedta Are you able to show me an example of what you mean sorry?

Comment: `<?php
        foreach($category as $cat){ 
    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $cat["cat_id"]; ?>" name="cat_no[]" id="box1"> <?php echo $cat["cat_title"]; ?></a><br>

    <?php
    }
    ?>` should be: `<?php foreach($category as $cat){ echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$cat["cat_id"].'" name="cat_no[]" id="box1">'.$cat["cat_title"].'</a><br>} ?>';` Like i've said before, this might be of little consequence.

Comment: @odedta That has broken the page - there are syntax errors in your example too